i18next language detection issues: Components not rendering correctly on first load
I'm building a portfolio website using Next.js and React with i18next for internationalization. My website supports English and German languages. However, when I visit the site for the first time (e.g., using an incognito window), some components don't load/render correctly. It seems like the language detection or initialization is causing issues, and components are not displaying as expected until I manually switch the language using the language switcher.
For instance, my Projects component doesn't render on the first load if the browser language is not set to English or German. If the browser language is set to English (en) or German (de), the components render correctly. However, if the language is set to Spanish (es), the component does not render correctly. Here's an example of the Projects component:
"use client";
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import SectionHeading from "./Section-heading";
import { projectsData } from "@/lib/data";
import { projectsDataDe } from "@/lib/dataDe";
import { useScroll, useTransform, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useSectionInView } from "@/lib/hooks";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export default function Projects() {
  const { ref } = useSectionInView("Projects");
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (i18n.language) {
      case "en":
        setProjects(projectsData);
        break;
      case "de":
        setProjects(projectsDataDe);
    }
  }, [i18n.language]);

  return (
    <section id="projects" ref={ref} className="mb-28 max-w-[53rem] scroll-mt-28 text-center sm:mb-40">
      <SectionHeading title={t("my_projects_title")} />
      <div>
        {projects &&
          projects.map((project: any) => (
            <Fragment key={project.id}>
              <Project {...project} />
            </Fragment>
          ))}
      </div>
      <h2 className="mb-28 max-w-[53rem] scroll-mt-28 text-center sm:mb-40">
        {t("more_projects")}
      </h2>
    </section>
  );
}

I also have a LanguageSwitch component that allows users to switch between languages manually:
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export default function LanguageSwitch() {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = (lang: string) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative" style={{ zIndex: 9999 }}>
      <select
        className="fixed top-5 right-5 bg-white w-[3rem] h-[3rem] bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur-[0.5rem] border border-gray-950 border-opacity-40 shadow-2x1 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center hover:scale-[1.15] active:scale-105 transition-all dark:bg-gray-950 dark:border-white"
        onChange={(e) => changeLanguage(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="en"></option>
        <option value="de"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

i18next configuration:
I am using i18next with react-i18next and i18next-browser-languagedetector. Here is my i18n configuration:
"use client";
import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";

i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: true,
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          // English translations...
        },
      },
      de: {
        translation: {
          // German translations...
        },
      },
    },
    detection: {
      order: ['localStorage', 'cookie', 'navigator'],
      caches: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],
      checkWhitelist: true,
    },
  });

Console message:
Upon first load, I see this in the console:
i18next: languageChanged es-ES

It seems the language detector is selecting es-ES (Spanish) as the default language (navigator language), but I only support en and de. I'm not sure if this is related to the components not rendering correctly, but the issue is resolved only after switching the language manually with the language switcher.
Question:

Why are components like my Projects component not rendering correctly on the first load, but display fine after switching the language?
How can I ensure that the correct language is detected and that the components render properly on the first load?
Is the language detection causing the issue? If so, how can I ensure that unsupported languages like es-ES fall back to en as expected?

I have tried setting fallbackLng and limiting supportedLngs, but the issue persists.
